# Print ZPL file programmatically in Android without PDF direct Software installed

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, zebra-printers, zpl

Hi I am working on an application which requires to print ZPl file using ZQ320 printer via a Bluetooth connection, the SDK am using is in the following link https://github.com/ZebraDevs/LinkOS-Android-Samples/tree/PDFPrint.

The above link is used to print PDF files using zebra printers. How do I print ZPL files without using PDF direct software installed in the printer. If any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Zebra Printer SDK -

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html

This SDK has Bluetooth connection classes, status, and methods to send ZPL.

The following example shows much of what you want to do. Replace the looper usage with the newer threading methods.

https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/android/

Comment: great - thanks for the update - nice to know

Comment: The only mistake I did was checking if pdf was enabled or not, excluding that rest of the functionality worked fine.